# Azure Function boilerplate code from visual studio cannot find namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure Function project in Visual Studio 2019. I go through all the prompts and the project is created.
However, when I switch to the code file, I see that there are red squiggly lines all over. It seems the project cannot find any of the dependencies.

I try adding the dependencies via right clicking on the suggestions which I see adds them in the csproj file and in the dependencies section in the solution explorer. But that does not fix the issue.

Running `dotnet restore` completes successfully, but does not solve the issue. I still have the red lines saying that the namespaces cannot be found and the yellow triangle on all of my dependencies.

I believe this has to be an issue with my environment since I have not actually written any code yet. I believe I have all the SDKs installed to build azure functions with .NET core. This is using .NET Core 2.1.

Thanks!

UPDATE - I tried opening an Azure Functions project from another group and I was able to build and run the project. I tried comparing the .csproj files but nothing was obvious as to why I would not be able to find any dependencies. The only difference was that in my .csproj file, there were many more Package References which I had added via NuGet. The only common package reference was `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`

Comment: Do you have `azure func core tools` installed ?

Comment: Could you please update your vs 2019 to the latest version or reinstall your vs 2019 ? I don't think we need to do any more operations if we create azure function in vs 2019.

Comment: I do have `azure function core tools` installed and I just re-installed VS 2019. I have version 16.5.2 of Visual Studio 2019 installed/

Comment: So did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @HuryShen yes I did

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by creating a new Azure Function project in a different folder. When I created the new project in a different folder, it worked without an issue. Then I tried renaming the folder that I wanted to use and that fixed the issue. The folder name had a URL encoded space (%20). When I changed the %20 to a '-', that resolved the issue.

The folder name had the '%20' in the name because when I cloned the repo, I did not change the default folder name which had a '%20' because there is a space in the repository name and had to be encoded in the clone url.

Also, I do not know why that solved the issue.